Random sample of the search result?
I am looking at how the word maybe is used in COCA. As I
want to analyze the contexts it occurs in, I need to random-sample the search result (which is around 374K hits), so that I can see in what kind of environments the word was used with a small, manageable sample.
Is there any way to random sample the search result? The only way I
could think of was keep taking every n th token in the output, but I am sure there should be a better way.
Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This question is similar to: Is there a way for random term extraction when searching COCA (the Corpus of Contemporary American English)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
